# two estimates in the proof of the boundary regularity of the elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

I'm reading a [note](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pdes.html) on the boundary regularity of the following equation:
[image]

[image]

**In the first step of the proof, the problem is reduced to the upper half space case:**
[image]

> Here are my **questions**:
>   Why we need to do the estimates separately? Why in the inner regularity case, there is no such issue?

---

**For the rest of the proof, two main estimates are given and put together to reach the conclusion.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question was not asked in a very good way and there are lots of "noises" there. Hunter wrote his notes based on Evans's book on PDEs. The following excerpt in Evans essentially explains why one needs to do the estimate in two different cases when considering the boundary regularity instead of the inner regularity.

> [image]
>   [image]